# Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html> in JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below script on the WordPress theme for navigation.

Now when I validate my below script using [this](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) tool then I am getting the below error.

I added this script before closing the body and I already have the below code in my HTML page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
```

Any idea how to solve this

[image]

```
/**
     * File navigation.js.
     *
     * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens and enables TAB key
     * navigation support for dropdown menus.
     */
    (function() {
      const siteNavigation = document.getElementById('site-navigation');

      // Return early if the navigation doesn't exist.
      if (!siteNavigation) {
        return;
      }

      const button = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

      // Return early if the button doesn't exist.
      if ('undefined' === typeof button) {
        return;
      }

      const menu = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

      // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
      if ('undefined' === typeof menu) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
      }

      if (!menu.classList.contains('nav-menu')) {
        menu.classList.add('nav-menu');
      }

      // Toggle the .toggled class and the aria-expanded value each time the button is clicked.
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        siteNavigation.classList.toggle('toggled');

        if (button.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {
          button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        } else {
          button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        }
      });

      // Remove the .toggled class and set aria-expanded to false when the user clicks outside the navigation.
      document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const isClickInside = siteNavigation.contains(event.target);

        if (!isClickInside) {
          siteNavigation.classList.remove('toggled');
          button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        }
      });

      // Get all the link elements within the menu.
      const links = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');

      // Get all the link elements with children within the menu.
      const linksWithChildren = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a');

      // Toggle focus each time a menu link is focused or blurred.
      for (const link of links) {
        link.addEventListener('focus', toggleFocus, true);
        link.addEventListener('blur', toggleFocus, true);
      }

      // Toggle focus each time a menu link with children receive a touch event.
      for (const link of linksWithChildren) {
        link.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleFocus, false);
      }

      /**
       * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
       */
      function toggleFocus() {
        if (event.type === 'focus' || event.type === 'blur') {
          let self = this;
          // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
          while (!self.classList.contains('nav-menu')) {
            // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
            if ('li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
              self.classList.toggle('focus');
            }
            self = self.parentNode;
          }
        }

        if (event.type === 'touchstart') {
          const menuItem = this.parentNode;
          event.preventDefault();
          for (const link of menuItem.parentNode.children) {
            if (menuItem !== link) {
              link.classList.remove('focus');
            }
          }
          menuItem.classList.toggle('focus');
        }
      }
    }());
```

Comment: Why do you validate the JavaScript file using an HTML validator?

Comment: what stupid I am. thank you for helping Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a HTML validator to validate a `.js` file, use [this validator](https://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php) instead.

Comment: Unless this JavaScript is inline in that case you provided insufficient information.